# How to retry the task when aiohttp.ClientSession fails in async

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am struggling to understand this behavior as I am new to async functions in Python.

I am trying to create this simple download tool and I have this function

```
async def download_all_pages(sites):
    print('Running download all pages')
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(safe_download_page(session,url)) for url in sites]
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions = True)
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                print("Got CancelledError")
    except (aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError, aiohttp.ClientResponseError,aiohttp.ClientConnectorError) as s:
        print("Oops, the server connection was dropped before we finished.")
        print(s)
```

I init this function like below :

```
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(download_all_pages([url+'/'+str(i) for i in range(1, nb_pages+1)]))
    loop.run_until_complete(download_all_sites([result['href'] for result in results]))
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
print('Finished at '+str(datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())))
```

Whenever I get an error, in this example mainly a aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError; the output show

```
Oops, the server connection was dropped before we finished.
Server disconnected
Finished at 1606440807.007339
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

... and just a million `Task was destroyed but it is pending!`

So when this error occurs, I dont want the function to finish since there are still a lot of tasks to achieve; hence the error **Task was destroyed but it is pending!**.

And as you can see, it calls the *print('Finished at')* before it even called the **loop.run_until_complete(download_all_sites([result['href'])**; it seems to completely exit the whole script. *(EDIT : I think I found out why this happens.
Because of the try: above, since it fails, it goes straight to the finally: clause therefore destroying pending tasks. Still the question of how to avoid that whole disconnect issue remains)*

Do you have any idea how I could safely retry the task that had the aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError error ?

Does this have to do with not using `if __name__ == "__main__":` ?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this have to do with not using `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

It doesn't have to do with not using `if __name__ == "__main__"`. It has to do with not handling exceptions in the right place. `asyncio.gather()` starts the given tasks and returns a tuple of their results. If any of those tasks raises an exception, `gather()` immediately raises the same exception without waiting for the remaining tasks to finish.

You should handle exceptions in the function you didn't show, `safe_download_page`. Use `try` there, catch the aiohttp-related exceptions you can recover from, and try again and try again (using a loop if necessary, with a sleep between iterations) in case of error. Something like this (untested):

```
async def download_all_pages(sites):
    print('Running download all pages')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(safe_download_page(session,url)) for url in sites]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Got CancelledError")

async def safe_download_page(session, url):
    while True:
        try:
            async with sem:
                await download_page(session, url)
                break
        except (aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError, aiohttp.ClientResponseError,aiohttp.ClientConnectorError) as s:
            print("Oops, the server connection was dropped on ", url, ": ", s)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # don't hammer the server
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer. The function is `async def safe_download_page(session, url):
 async with sem:   download_page(session, url)` and `download_page` does a bunch of stuff relating to parsing and begins with `async with session.get(url) as response:`. So you're telling me that I  should remove the gather from download_all_sites, and put it where ? Or not use gather at all ? Like move all the `download_page` logic to the `safe_download_page` after the `async with sem:` and catch the `session.get(url)` errors ?

Comment: `gather` is fine, I was not suggesting that you remove it, I was just explaining what it does. I was suggesting that a `try` that catches exceptions should be in `safe_download_page`, not in `download_all_pages`.

Comment: @Raphaelmsr Also, I now see that you're using `return_exceptions=True`, which actually changes the behavior of `gather`. But my advice still applies; I've now amended the question to include an example of what I mean.

Comment: Sweet ! Saw your edit, awesome will try that and will let you know if I encounter any issues. EDIT : Isn't the while true going to cause infinite loops ; redoing tasks that had already been treated ? I encountered this behavior with  `while True`. Thanks !

Comment: EDIT 2 : I also see that you removed the `return await` before calling `download_page` and that you `break` the While loop; is there a reason for that ?

Comment: @Raphaelmsr The `while True` loop shouldn't be infinite because there is a `break` immediately after a successful download. I don't know what `return await` you are referring to, but I've now added an `await` in front of `download_page`, as `download_page` should most likely be async.

Comment: Very cool, thanks a million, will try all that